# compiling error using g++ in linux regarding std::basic_ios

Tags: c++, g++

I am try to port a C++ project develop in Visual C++ 2017 to redhat linux gcc 8.2. I encountered some strange errors using make command

```
Scanning dependencies of target XXX
[  7%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/XXX.dir/cashflowengine.cpp.o
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/c++allocator.h:33:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/allocator.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/string:41,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/program_options/errors.hpp:12,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/program_options/options_description.hpp:12,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/FileSettings.h:4,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/Assumption.h:6,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/DynamicTables.h:4,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/stdafx.h:3,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/cashflowengine.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ext/new_allocator.h: In instantiation of ‘void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = std::basic_istringstream<char>; _Args = {std::basic_istringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >}; _Tp = std::basic_istringstream<char>]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/alloc_traits.h:254:4:   required from ‘static typename std::enable_if<std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::__construct_helper<_Tp, _Args>::value, void>::type std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::_S_construct(_Alloc&, _Tp*, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = std::basic_istringstream<char>; _Args = {std::basic_istringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >}; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::basic_istringstream<char> >; typename std::enable_if<std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::__construct_helper<_Tp, _Args>::value, void>::type = void]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/alloc_traits.h:393:57:   required from ‘static decltype (_S_construct(__a, __p, (forward<_Args>)(std::allocator_traits::construct::__args)...)) std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::construct(_Alloc&, _Tp*, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = std::basic_istringstream<char>; _Args = {std::basic_istringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >}; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::basic_istringstream<char> >; decltype (_S_construct(__a, __p, (forward<_Args>)(std::allocator_traits::construct::__args)...)) = <type error>]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/vector.tcc:97:40:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::emplace_back(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {std::basic_istringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >}; _Tp = std::basic_istringstream<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::basic_istringstream<char> >]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_vector.h:920:36:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type&&) [with _Tp = std::basic_istringstream<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::basic_istringstream<char> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = std::basic_istringstream<char>]’
/home/research/QZ/files/XXX/utility.h:2413:37:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ext/new_allocator.h:120:4: error: use of deleted function ‘std::basic_istringstream<char>::basic_istringstream(const std::basic_istringstream<char>&)’
  { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
    ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/complex:45:0,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/detail/container_fwd.hpp:98,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/container_hash/extensions.hpp:22,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/container_hash/hash.hpp:760,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/type_index/stl_type_index.hpp:42,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/type_index.hpp:29,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/any.hpp:20,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/program_options/value_semantic.hpp:12,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/program_options/options_description.hpp:13,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/FileSettings.h:4,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/Assumption.h:6,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/DynamicTables.h:4,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/stdafx.h:3,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/cashflowengine.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/sstream:272:11: note: ‘std::basic_istringstream<char>::basic_istringstream(const std::basic_istringstream<char>&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
     class basic_istringstream : public basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>
           ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/sstream:272:11: error: use of deleted function ‘std::basic_istream<char>::basic_istream(const std::basic_istream<char>&)’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/sstream:38:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/complex:45,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/detail/container_fwd.hpp:98,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/container_hash/extensions.hpp:22,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/container_hash/hash.hpp:760,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/type_index/stl_type_index.hpp:42,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/type_index.hpp:29,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/any.hpp:20,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/program_options/value_semantic.hpp:12,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/program_options/options_description.hpp:13,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/FileSettings.h:4,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/Assumption.h:6,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/DynamicTables.h:4,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/stdafx.h:3,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/cashflowengine.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/istream:58:11: note: ‘std::basic_istream<char>::basic_istream(const std::basic_istream<char>&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
     class basic_istream : virtual public basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>
           ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/istream:58:11: error: use of deleted function ‘std::basic_ios<char>::basic_ios(const std::basic_ios<char>&)’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ios:44:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/istream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/sstream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/complex:45,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/detail/container_fwd.hpp:98,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/container_hash/extensions.hpp:22,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/container_hash/hash.hpp:760,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/type_index/stl_type_index.hpp:42,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/type_index.hpp:29,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/any.hpp:20,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/program_options/value_semantic.hpp:12,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/program_options/options_description.hpp:13,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/FileSettings.h:4,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/Assumption.h:6,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/DynamicTables.h:4,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/stdafx.h:3,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/cashflowengine.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/basic_ios.h:66:11: note: ‘std::basic_ios<char>::basic_ios(const std::basic_ios<char>&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
     class basic_ios : public ios_base
           ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ios:42:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/istream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/sstream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/complex:45,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/detail/container_fwd.hpp:98,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/container_hash/extensions.hpp:22,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/container_hash/hash.hpp:760,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/type_index/stl_type_index.hpp:42,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/type_index.hpp:29,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/any.hpp:20,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/program_options/value_semantic.hpp:12,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/program_options/options_description.hpp:13,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/FileSettings.h:4,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/Assumption.h:6,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/DynamicTables.h:4,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/stdafx.h:3,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/cashflowengine.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/ios_base.h:786:5: error: ‘std::ios_base::ios_base(const std::ios_base&)’ is private
     ios_base(const ios_base&);
     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ios:44:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/istream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/sstream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/complex:45,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/detail/container_fwd.hpp:98,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/container_hash/extensions.hpp:22,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/container_hash/hash.hpp:760,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/type_index/stl_type_index.hpp:42,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/type_index.hpp:29,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/any.hpp:20,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/program_options/value_semantic.hpp:12,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/program_options/options_description.hpp:13,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/FileSettings.h:4,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/Assumption.h:6,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/DynamicTables.h:4,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/stdafx.h:3,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/cashflowengine.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/basic_ios.h:66:11: error: within this context
     class basic_ios : public ios_base
           ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/complex:45:0,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/detail/container_fwd.hpp:98,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/container_hash/extensions.hpp:22,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/container_hash/hash.hpp:760,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/type_index/stl_type_index.hpp:42,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/type_index.hpp:29,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/any.hpp:20,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/program_options/value_semantic.hpp:12,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/program_options/options_description.hpp:13,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/FileSettings.h:4,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/Assumption.h:6,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/DynamicTables.h:4,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/stdafx.h:3,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/cashflowengine.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/sstream:272:11: error: use of deleted function ‘std::basic_ios<char>::basic_ios(const std::basic_ios<char>&)’
     class basic_istringstream : public basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>
           ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/sstream:272:11: error: use of deleted function ‘std::basic_stringbuf<char>::basic_stringbuf(const std::basic_stringbuf<char>&)’
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/sstream:64:11: note: ‘std::basic_stringbuf<char>::basic_stringbuf(const std::basic_stringbuf<char>&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
     class basic_stringbuf : public basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>
           ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ios:43:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/istream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/sstream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/complex:45,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/detail/container_fwd.hpp:98,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/container_hash/extensions.hpp:22,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/container_hash/hash.hpp:760,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/type_index/stl_type_index.hpp:42,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/type_index.hpp:29,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/any.hpp:20,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/program_options/value_semantic.hpp:12,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/program_options/options_description.hpp:13,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/FileSettings.h:4,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/Assumption.h:6,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/DynamicTables.h:4,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/stdafx.h:3,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/cashflowengine.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/streambuf:802:7: error: ‘std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_streambuf(const std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]’ is private
       basic_streambuf(const basic_streambuf& __sb)
       ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/complex:45:0,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/detail/container_fwd.hpp:98,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/container_hash/extensions.hpp:22,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/container_hash/hash.hpp:760,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/type_index/stl_type_index.hpp:42,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/type_index.hpp:29,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/any.hpp:20,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/program_options/value_semantic.hpp:12,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/program_options/options_description.hpp:13,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/FileSettings.h:4,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/Assumption.h:6,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/DynamicTables.h:4,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/stdafx.h:3,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/cashflowengine.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/sstream:64:11: error: within this context
     class basic_stringbuf : public basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>
           ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/vector:62:0,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/program_options/errors.hpp:14,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/program_options/options_description.hpp:12,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/FileSettings.h:4,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/Assumption.h:6,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/DynamicTables.h:4,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/stdafx.h:3,
                 from /home/research/QZ/files/XXX/cashflowengine.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_construct.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = std::basic_istringstream<char>; _Args = {std::basic_istringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >}]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:75:53:   required from ‘static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy<_TrivialValueTypes>::__uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator<std::basic_istringstream<char>*>; _ForwardIterator = std::basic_istringstream<char>*; bool _TrivialValueTypes = false]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:117:41:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator<std::basic_istringstream<char>*>; _ForwardIterator = std::basic_istringstream<char>*]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:258:63:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator<std::basic_istringstream<char>*>; _ForwardIterator = std::basic_istringstream<char>*; _Tp = std::basic_istringstream<char>]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:281:69:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_move_if_noexcept_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, _Allocator&) [with _InputIterator = std::basic_istringstream<char>*; _ForwardIterator = std::basic_istringstream<char>*; _Allocator = std::allocator<std::basic_istringstream<char> >]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/vector.tcc:415:43:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_emplace_back_aux(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {std::basic_istringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >}; _Tp = std::basic_istringstream<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::basic_istringstream<char> >]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/vector.tcc:101:54:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::emplace_back(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {std::basic_istringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >}; _Tp = std::basic_istringstream<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::basic_istringstream<char> >]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_vector.h:920:36:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type&&) [with _Tp = std::basic_istringstream<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::basic_istringstream<char> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = std::basic_istringstream<char>]’
/home/research/QZ/files/XXX/utility.h:2413:37:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: error: use of deleted function ‘std::basic_istringstream<char>::basic_istringstream(const std::basic_istringstream<char>&)’
     { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
       ^
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/XXX.dir/cashflowengine.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/XXX.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Most error pointed out are in C++ include files or boost library. For the project files, they are point to the lines where iostream or sstream is included.

I am not quite familiar with gcc and this may be a stupid question. I notice the include file is in /usr/include/4.8.2. I am using gcc 8.2. Is this the right folder or my include file version is outdated. If so, how could I update the include library?

If the include file version is the problem, how should I debug this? Thanks

Follow up:

It turns out in the code (utility.h)  I have something like this

```
vector<istringstream> sstr;
TrimString(str1);
TrimString(str2);
sstr.push_back(istringstream(str1));
sstr.push_back(istringstream(str2));
```

Comment out this part solve the problem. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Looks like the MSVS code was using non standard extensions.  A lot of the error appear to be from code in `cashflowengine.cpp`.  Can you make a [mre] out of that file that gives you these compiler errors?

Comment: @NathanOliver, thanks so much for the help. It turn out there is a vector of istringstream and push_back is used. Comment out this part solve the problem. It is nice to learn that MSVS was using non standard extensions.

Comment: `/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/` - this doesn't seem to match well with your claim of using gcc 8.2...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ext/new_allocator.h:120:4: error: use of deleted function ‘std::basic_istringstream<char>::basic_istringstream(const std::basic_istringstream<char>&)’`

This indicates you're trying to copy an std::basic_istream.

std::basic_istream has an explicitly deleted copy constructor

Comment: np, feel free to mark the answer as "this resolved my issue"